# How can I initialize a custom Type that conform to Decodable with Decodable initializer?

Tags: swift

Here is my tried code so far, frankly I think it is not possible, but I am not sure.

How can I initialize a custom Type that conform to Decodable with Decodable initializer?

```
struct CustomType: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int?
}



func test() {
    
    let stringOfJSON: String = """
    {
        "name": "SwiftPunk",
        "age": 35
    }
    """

    let dataOfJSON: Data? = stringOfJSON.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    
    let customType1: CustomType = try! JSONDecoder().decode(CustomType.self, from: dataOfJSON!)
    
    print(customType1)
    
    let customType2: CustomType = try! CustomType(from: <#T##Decoder#>)
    
    print(customType2)
}
```

Comment: Well, you'd need a `Decoder`, which you'd normally get from the parameter of `init(from:Decoder)` when implementing custom decoding, or if you have implemented your own decoder. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Any possible way that make me be able use Decodable initializer. That is my goal.

Comment: You need to create a custom initialiser to initialise your type in another (manual) way.

Comment: My goal was using already exist init of CustomType coming with Decodable. So basically you say, it is not possible? @JoakimDanielson

Comment: Yes it is not possible with a reasonable effort. Like Sweeper implies in the first comment you could write your own decoding implementation but I am pretty sure that is not what you are after here.

Comment: I am confused a little! If we cannot use the init coming with Decodable, then why it exist as init? I mean it could be defined as a function, right? why as init tho?! @JoakimDanielson

Comment: When you adopt `Decodable` you get `init(from decoder` for free  in a protocol extension. If you want to init an instance by `name` and `age` use `CustomType(name:age:)` which is also provided for free. By the way `SONDecoder().decode(CustomType.self` **does** call `init(from decoder`

Comment: @vadian: Thanks, it is clear for my that I can initialize a CustomType with `CustomType(name:age:)` no issue there, also that was crystal clear that I am getting that initialization and `init(from decoder)` for free, It was not clear for me that how could I be able take use of `init(from decoder)` for CustomType initialization

Comment: You take use of it when decoding the JSON with `JSONDecoder().decode(CustomType.self` and you can take use of it when you implement the method to write you own custom logic. But the method cannot be called directly. Accept the fact.

Comment: @vadian: I was aware that the `init(from decoder)` is in used for `JSONDecoder().decode(CustomType.self ...` I was hopping that I could use `init(from decoder)` for initialization for CustomType beside having the `CustomType(name:age:)`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What are you going to pass in the `decoder` parameter? The method is being synthesized by the framework to decode and assign the values to the appropriate struct members according to the (also synthesized) CodingKeys.

Comment: Why? Because I want to use that initialization. I do not understand why you are asking why do I want to do that?!

Comment: @swiftPunk did you mean `CustomType(from: data)`? Why don't you use that decoding method on data I suggested yesterday `let customType2: CustomType = try data.decodedObject()`

Comment: @LeoDabus: Let me know if I am clear, see the direct implantation of `Decodable` for yourself, if you see it you will see we are decoding from container to component of custom struct right? so in the fact we are doing initialization with that protocol, I want do the initialization tho and use that instance. `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws { let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Codingkeys.self); self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name) ...`

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two situations in which you would need to directly call the `init(from: Decoder)` initialiser.

#### When implementing custom decoding

There might be cases where you want to decode another object using the same decoder. As a very contrived example:

```
struct Person: Decodable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int?
}

struct PersonWithHeight: Decodable {
    let person: Person
    let heightInCm: Int
    
    enum CodingKeys : CodingKey {
        case heightInCm
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // Person.init(from:) is being used here!
        person = try Person(from: decoder)
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        heightInCm = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .heightInCm)
    }
}
```

This can be used to decode JSON such as:

```
{ "name": "Sweeper", "age": 30, "heightInCm": 171 }
```

#### When implementing your own decoder

You might want to implement your own decoder to decode custom data formats. For example, you could write an internal class that conforms to `Decoder`:

```
class MyCustomDecoderImpl: Decoder {
    ...
}
```

And expose a public struct that has `decode<T: Decodable>(_: T.Type, from: Data)` method. And at some point in the implementation, you will have to call `init(from: decoder)`, where `decoder` is an instance of `MyCustomDecoderImpl`.

For a concrete example, see [XMLDecoder.swift](https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/XMLCoder/blob/main/Sources/XMLCoder/Decoder/XMLDecoder.swift) and [XMLDecoderImplementation.swift](https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/XMLCoder/blob/main/Sources/XMLCoder/Decoder/XMLDecoderImplementation.swift#L455) from this XML decoder that I randomly found.

If you *really* want to call `CustomType(from:)` directly, you would need to, like in the above example, create a custom `Decoder`. Here is a rather barebones implementation of one, where I throw errors in all the methods that are not needed in decoding a `CustomType`:

```
class TotallyUneccessaryDecoder: Decoder {
    struct KeyedContainer<Key: CodingKey>: KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol {
        var codingPath: [CodingKey] = []
        
        var allKeys: [Key] = [Key(stringValue: "name"), Key(stringValue: "age")].compactMap { $0 }
        
        func contains(_ key: Key) -> Bool {
            allKeys.contains(where: { $0.stringValue == key.stringValue })
        }
        
        func decodeNil(forKey key: Key) throws -> Bool {
            if contains(key) {
                return false
            } else {
                throw DecodingError.keyNotFound(key, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "key not found", underlyingError: nil))
            }
        }
        
        func decode(_ type: Bool.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> Bool {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))
        }
        
        func decode(_ type: String.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> String {
            if key.stringValue == "name" {
                return "Sweeper"
            } else {
                throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(String.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))
            }
        }
        
        func decode(_ type: Double.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> Double {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))
        }
        
        func decode(_ type: Float.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> Float {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))

        }
        
        func decode(_ type: Int.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> Int {
            if key.stringValue == "age" {
                return 30
            } else {
                throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(Int.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))
            }
        }
        
        func decode(_ type: Int8.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> Int8 {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))
        }
        
        func decode(_ type: Int16.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> Int16 {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))

        }
        
        func decode(_ type: Int32.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> Int32 {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))

        }
        
        func decode(_ type: Int64.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> Int64 {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))

        }
        
        func decode(_ type: UInt.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> UInt {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))

        }
        
        func decode(_ type: UInt8.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> UInt8 {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))

        }
        
        func decode(_ type: UInt16.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> UInt16 {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))

        }
        
        func decode(_ type: UInt32.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> UInt32 {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))

        }
        
        func decode(_ type: UInt64.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> UInt64 {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))

        }
        
        func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> T where T : Decodable {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Bool.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "type mismatch", underlyingError: nil))

        }
        
        func nestedContainer<NestedKey>(keyedBy type: NestedKey.Type, forKey key: Key) throws -> KeyedDecodingContainer<NestedKey> where NestedKey : CodingKey {
            throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(KeyedDecodingContainer<NestedKey>.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "no nested container", underlyingError: nil))

        }
        
        func nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey key: Key) throws -> UnkeyedDecodingContainer {
            throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(UnkeyedDecodingContainer.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "no nested container", underlyingError: nil))
        }
        
        func superDecoder() throws -> Decoder {
            throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(Decoder.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "no super decoder", underlyingError: nil))
        }
        
        func superDecoder(forKey key: Key) throws -> Decoder {
            throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(Decoder.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "no super decoder", underlyingError: nil))
        }
        
        
    }
    
    var codingPath: [CodingKey] = []
    
    var userInfo: [CodingUserInfoKey : Any] = [:]
    
    func container<Key>(keyedBy type: Key.Type) throws -> KeyedDecodingContainer<Key> where Key : CodingKey {
        KeyedDecodingContainer(KeyedContainer())
    }
    
    func unkeyedContainer() throws -> UnkeyedDecodingContainer {
        throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(UnkeyedDecodingContainer.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "no unkeyed container", underlyingError: nil))
    }
    
    func singleValueContainer() throws -> SingleValueDecodingContainer {
        throw DecodingError.valueNotFound(SingleValueDecodingContainer.self, .init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "no single value container", underlyingError: nil))
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
print(try CustomType(from: TotallyUneccessaryDecoder()))
```

and it would print:

```
CustomType(name: "Sweeper", age: Optional(30))
```

But *please* don't do this. This is not how this API is designed to be used.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot follow what are you did, all I wanted to initialize CustomType of `init(from decoder)`

Comment: But why 2 Types in your answer? I have just 1 Type. I am thinking you and I are not in same page. sorry if i was not clear.

Comment: Yes, I know it. All I want is: initialization CustomType with help of `init(from:)`

Comment: @swiftPunk I've changed `Foo` and `Bar` to just `Person`, which is structurally the same as your `CustomType`. After the `person = try Person(from: decoder)` line, you have done "initialization CustomType with help of `init(from:)`". Is that clearer now? Or do you mean you don't want to do this in another `init(from:)`? In that case you'll need to implement your own `Decoder` to pass into the `init`, as well as keyed and unkeyed decoding containers and all that kind of stuff.

Comment: @swiftPunk I have added a bare bones implementation which is only useful for initialising `CustomType` and not anything else. If you want something more useful, you should not directly use `init(from:)`.

Comment: OMG! So many code, I would not use that initialization for sure. I was thinking maybe I could just pass Data to `init(from:)` and make it work with data! But I am thinking it is really bad naming! Apple should not make it as init, they could make it as a func, like they done for encoding.

Comment: @swiftPunk Well you can make add an initialiser to `TotallyUneccessaryDecoder` that takes a data, and have it pass that to `KeyedContainer`, and update the implementation of the methods to read the things you want from the `Data`. But that will be more complicated and I will not be writing that code for you. You are not supposed to do it that way anyway. Have a look at the XML decoder I linked to see how it is designed to work.

Comment: I do know why you do not want initialization a type with data, it could be time saving and no need to explicitly  `JSONDecoder().decode(..`